# Modify swiftui back button

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to modify swiftui back button by giving it different word and color. But an extra back button still appear even i did not include it.
How can i get rid of it and make my cancel button does the navigate back like the original back button?

[extra button appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEm1B.jpg)

```
 import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: SeaView()) {
            Text("SeaView")
        }
    }
  }
}

struct SeaView: View {
 var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("Fish")
        Text("Octopus")
        Text("Shark")
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Button("Cancel") {
                
            }.foregroundColor(Color.red)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to @Asperi's answer, have a look at using [.cancellationAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement/cancellationaction/) for the placement to position the Cancel button depending on the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide default one explicitly, like

```
List {
    Text("Fish")
    Text("Octopus")
    Text("Shark")
}
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)   // << here !!
```